# What is another word or phrase for "from ... onward"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

What is another word or phrase (other than "since") for "from ... onward"?

> **From Beethoven onward**, composers notated dynamics in a more direct and
>   detailed manner.

Comment: Maybe... *after*?

Comment: Or *beginning with...*.

Comment: What about "as from"?

Answer (score 1):

Henceforth?
How do you plan to use this word?

Answer (score 0):

Subsequent- Subsequently to Beethoven.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subsequent